# Convert 1347616929 into dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss format

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, datetime

I have a date time in milliseconds, e.g. 1347616929, and I want to convert it to get the date and time in a "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.

Comment: Milliseconds since what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to convert miliseconds in to seconds by dividing miliseconds by 1000.

```
   NSTimeInterval timeInSecond = 1347616929/1000;
   NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInSecond];
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *formattedDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
   NSLog(@"Formatted Date : %@",formattedDate);
```

Comment: But if its miliseconds, then you have to divide it by 1000 because [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:] will take nstimeinterval in second.

Comment: I haven't divided  but it still shows correct,so will it cause any problem?

Comment: @Anand Then, as I noted in my answer, the number is probably not really milliseconds but seconds since 1970.

Comment: Its may be you already have second value ie. 1347616929 is in second. Otherwise [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:] will take NSTimeInterval in seconds , thats for sure. See NSDate apple documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really milliseconds, you can use something like;

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1347616929/1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

If you want to keep the milliseconds, you'll have to add `1347616929%1000` milliseconds to the NSDate also.

The offset really looks like seconds though, which means you can use it as seconds right away;

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1347616929];
```

After you've converted, you can format it using normal NSDateFormatter functions to format it as you want;

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy' 'hh':'mm':'ss'.'SSS"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: thanks , but will this cause any problem when timezone is changed?

Comment: @Anand The offset is from GMT, so it's a fixed moment in time but it's not the same time of day in every time zone (for example, if it's 1am GMT, it may be 2am CET and 7pm the day before EST, but it's still the same moment) Whether this is a problem is entirely up to the rest of your code.

Comment: hummm your are right,now what should be the solution,to make it work in all time zone

Comment: @Anand Depends what your code needs the NSDate for, you may want to ask a new question once you have an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: for now i m done with my requirement, if causes problem,then i will sure come back to you, ok thanks once again.